# message broker data connection with oracle express 11g

Tags: oracle, messagebroker

How to make "oracle 11g express" connection from web-sphere message broker 8?

it is giving an error "invalid driver definition, jar not found".

Answer (score 1):

File>New Database Definition File. Then new connection, choose JDBC driver as Oracle 11- Oracle thin driver default. Click on the triangle beside it and choose the path of the driver from your PC.